# Javascript grouping by day of month

Tags: javascript

I have the following JSON object returned by an API call

```
Object {Result: Array[5]}
Result: Array[5]
0: Object
  id: 1
  name: "Mark"
  joinDate: 2014-05-03T22:12:05.000Z
  balance: 2201
1: Object
2: Object
3: Object
4: Object
5: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

I need to group the data here and produce a new object grouping number of clients and their balances in each day of the month. So that I end up with an object that has (assuming I am producing an object for May based on the object above):

```
{
   0:Object
    id: 1 >> Referring to Day 1 of the month
    nof_of_clients: 5
    total_balance: 30,899
   1:Object
    id: 2 >> Referring to Day 2 of the month
    nof_of_clients: 12
    total_balance: 20000
   2:Object
    id: 5 >> Referring to Day 5 of the month
    nof_of_clients: 2
    total_balance: 1200
}
```

So I was wondering is it possible to do this by Javascript and if yes, how? Any example will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you would need to loop through your results and generate an object which groups the data as you want. First you need to calculate the day, month and year of each result:

```
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    result[i].day=result[i].joinDate.split('T')[0];
    var arr=result[i].day.split('-');
    result[i].day_of_month=Number(arr[2]);
    result[i].month=Number(arr[1]);
    result[i].year=Number(arr[0]);
}
```

Then you need to loop through the results and generate an object which groups by year,month,day:

```
var arr={};
for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    current=result[i];
    if(!arr.hasOwnProperty(current.year)){//if year doesnt exist, create year
       arr[current.year]={};   
    }
    if(!arr[current.year].hasOwnProperty(current.month)){// if month doesnt exist, create month
        arr[current.year][current.month]={};
    }
    if(!arr[current.year][current.month].hasOwnProperty(current.day)){//if day doesnt exist, create day
        arr[current.year][current.month][current.day]={
            id:current.day_of_month,
            nof_of_clients:1,
            total_balance:current.balance
        }
    }else{//if day already exists, add 1 to the number of client and add the balance to total balance
         arr[current.year][current.month][current.day].nof_of_clients+=1;
         arr[current.year][current.month][current.day].total_balance+=current.balance;
    }
}
```

Here is a full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/3auBG/1/

Answer (score 1):

While looping through `Result` first we create a date object from `joinDate` string using `Date` method, then we group items into a new object `groupedResult` by year/month/day order:

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var groupedResult = [];
for (var i = 0; i < Result.length; i++)
{
    var date = new Date(Result[i].joinDate), day = date.getDate(), month = months[date.getMonth()], year = date.getFullYear(), d = "day " + day;

    if (!groupedResult.hasOwnProperty(year)) groupedResult[year] = {};
    if (!groupedResult[year].hasOwnProperty(month)) groupedResult[year][month] = {};
    if (groupedResult[year][month].hasOwnProperty(d))
    {
        groupedResult[year][month][d].no_of_clients += 1;
        groupedResult[year][month][d].balance += Result[i].balance;
    }
    else groupedResult[year][month][d] = {"id": day, "no_of_clients": 1, "balance": Result[i].balance};
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/BYDN4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Pnax8/1

- Loop through the array of results
- Parse the date (with regex, could be done with momentjs instead), and check if it already exists in our object
  `RegExp("^([0-9]{1,4})-([0-9]{1,2})-([0-9]{1,2})T([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2}):([0-9]{1,2})(.([0-9]+))?Z$")`
- If not, create a new entry
- Add to number of clients and the total balance

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idear:

- Write a new js class, it has day,nof_of_clients,total_balance,
- write a sort function objSortFun(a,b) for the object, compare by day,
- create an array of the type,
- write a add method, it first look for existing day, you can do 1 by 1, but better by binary search, if found then append value to it, if not found then create a new object, and call the Array.sort(arr, objSortFun) method to do sort,
- call the add method for each object in json array returned,